# Error: Command \ invalid in math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros

I am getting the following error:

```
Command \  invalid in math mode.
```

Why? Compilation ends but no PDF is created because of those errors.
This seems to be the problematic piece of code but I don't understand the error I'm getting:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:e211}
I_C = C \dfrac{dv_c}{dt} \xRightarrow{Em regime estacionário} I=I_C=C.0=0
\end{equation}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: That error message is _not_ possible with your code snippet! It must be in another math environment.

Comment: It is not the cause of your error but the text `Em regime estacionário` should not be in math mode, it should be `\text{Em regime estacionário}`

Answer (score 4):

Please always post complete documents that show the error, and also show the exact error generated by TeX (the format you showed is not a tex error).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:e211}
I_C = C \dfrac{dv_c}{dt} \xRightarrow{Em regime estacionário} I=I_C=C.0=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Produces

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 I_C = C \dfrac{dv_c}{dt} \xRightarrow
```

If I change that to `\Rightarrow` I get

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \' invalid in math mode on input line 10.

! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.
```

Which is I assume, the error you got.

Here you get a LaTeX warning (not an error) about `\'{a}` but then immediately get 
a lower level TeX error about the same issue. (Even though the text is entered as `á` `inputenc` converts this to traditional TeX markup of `\'{a}` as the rest of the system is not unicode-aware.

So in fact my initial comment on the question *is* the source of the error. Even without the error over á you should never use the math italic font for natural language words or multi-letter identifiers, it is designed to make adjacent letters *not* look like a word, but rather as a product of separate 1-letter identifiers.

This runs without error

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:e211}
I_C = C \dfrac{dv_c}{dt} \Rightarrow \text{Em regime estacionário}
\qquad I=I_C=C.0=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]